# Como implmento una cardview en un fragmento, en Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment, kotlin, cardview

Soy nuevo en el desarrollo de android, y no se como implementar una cardview que funcione en un fragmento. Cabe mencionar que en mi proyecto, tengo mi activity_main dividido en dos fragmentos, en uno de ellos es donde quiero que se muestre la cardview. Anexo lo que intente hacer en el fragment:

class MarcaFragment : Fragment() {

```
private lateinit var card: RecyclerView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.tienda_card)

    card = findViewById(R.id.cardTienda)

    iniciarCard1()
}

fun iniciarCard1() {

    card.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    card.setHasFixedSize(true)
    card.adapter = AdaptadorCard(this, getTienda())
}

fun getTienda(): MutableList<Tienda> {
    val tiendas: MutableList<Tienda> = mutableListOf()
    tiendas.add(Tienda(R.mipmap.hogar, "Hogar"))
    tiendas.add(Tienda(R.mipmap.deporte, "Deportes"))
    tiendas.add(Tienda(R.mipmap.joyeria, "Joyeria"))
    tiendas.add(Tienda(R.mipmap.moda, "Moda"))
    tiendas.add(Tienda(R.mipmap.tecno, "Tecnología"))

    return tiendas
}
```

}

Comment: Necesitas un Layout aparte que será el cardView
Donde definiras los elementos que tendrá el CardView

Comment: Necesitas... 
1- RecyclerView que contendra tus cardsViews
2- Un cardView modelo que sera cada item del RecyclerView